# Calculating the total sum of alternating series

Tags: summation, summation-method

I've been asked to calculate the exact form of the total sum of two alternating series, if possible. The sum of the series are the following:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{i·\log(i)}{1+i^3} $$ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{i^2·\log(i)}{1+i^3} $$

I know the first one is absolute convergent, and the second one is conditionally convergent. My question is: Is there any way of calculating the exact result of any of them by hand? If so, how could I do it? I'd usually do it by partial sums, but it doesn't seem possible this time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Calling $$ f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^i \frac{i^x}{1+i^3}\hspace{0.3cm}\text{with}\hspace{0.3cm}x<3$$

the results you are looking for are $f'(1)$ and $f'(2)$. Now, $f(x)$ seems to be related with *polygamma function* $\psi^\nu(z)$